# batch copy and paste of 200 text files into a single document file in windows

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, batch

I used OCR to extract text from 200 images now I have 200 .txt files that I must copy all .txt file into single word document.I search for two solutions

immediate: find a way to copy all text to a .doc file automatically.

ideal: first copy image and then its OCR text automatically. for example copy 29.jpg to word document and then copy 29.txt and so on...
any suggestion is welcomed.

OS: Windows 10

Python: installed

Text: UTF-8

Comment: You might want to write a small Python script to concatenate the files like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13613336/python-concatenate-text-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all suggestions work for the first request. thank you

I used the link MSC provided and write a script in python which is a solution for the second request. however, because of utf-8 encoding problem in Windows machine (made me crazy), it just works on a Linux if you know how to overcome utf-8 encoding problem in windows please comment.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches
document = Document()
p = document.add_paragraph()
r = p.add_run()
for i in range(29,48):
    r.add_picture(str(i)+'.jpg',width=Inches(6.2), height=Inches(9))
    with open(str(i)+'.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f:
            r.add_text(line)
document.save('test.docx')
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a batch file with the following:

```
CD OCRFolder
copy OCR*.txt > NewFile.txt
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\winword.exe Newfile.txt
del OCR.txt
```

This will navigate to the folder that holds the OCR files. - `CD OCRFolder`

Merge all the OCR text files into 1 text file - `copy OCR*.txt > NewFile.txt`

Open the new file in Word - `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\winword.exe Newfile.txt`

Your location of WinWOrd.exe may be different depending on your version of Word.

Comment: `winword.exe` should be in your path, so you can just write `winword.exe`.

Comment: I find that "Should Be"  and "Are" are usually two different things.  That's why I explicitly added the path.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Since you're asking to combine them into a .doc file, I'm assuming you have Microsoft Office installed.</sup>

Open Microsoft Office, selecting the Insert tab. Click the down arrow next to `Object`, and select the `Text from File` option.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to select all the files you want to join together.

Note: if any conversion is necessary, it will mean a few extra clicks... per file!

To add the pictures to the document, on the same Insert tab there's an option to insert pictures, here you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to add all your pictures. However, it will not be able add them alternating after your text.

Comment: thank you, it works just costs 200 clicks :). how about the second?

Comment: @imi If they're the only files in the folder you can just do `ctrl-a` (and if not, but they're consecutive, you can use `shift` and `page-down`, etc.). As far as the second request, order them alternatively, e.g. 1.txt 1.jpg 2.txt etc., and it should (I haven't tried it) combine them in that order.

Comment: I mean 200 clicks for confirmation of utf-8 encoding and ... not selecting files. for the second solution when I insert jpg file as text word converts it to text (so messy). your first solution is ok :)